# Who is Mr. JOBS?

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

MR. ORAN is FRENCH

MR. DEO is BRITISH

MR. FLY is IRISH

MR. TSU is BRAZILIAN

MR. JOBS is ______ ?

**Why?**

> *Note*: I need to give some credit to another puzzle but if I did now, it would constitute a major clue. So pardon me if I wait till the answers are in

Comment: Steve Jobs is American?

Comment: FUNNY Rand al'Thor.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MR. JOBS is...

> **Chinese**

Because:

> The names are codes for companies on stock exchange market.
>  https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/JOBS/profile?p=JOBS

The others are:

- MR. ORAN is:

> [Orange S.A. (ORAN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orange_S.A.): a French multinational telecommunications corporation.

- MR. DEO is:

> [Diageo plc (DEO)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diageo): a British multinational alcoholic beverages company.

- MR. FLY is:

> [FLY Leasing Limited (FLY)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLY_Leasing): an aircraft leasing investment company (based in Dublin, Ireland).

- MR. TSU is:

> [TIM Participações S.A. (TSU)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TIM_Brasil): the Brazilian subsidiary of Telecom Italia Mobile, an Italian telecommunications company.

Comment: Good Job. This puzzle was inspired  from a Tom K puzzle on Airport Codes

Comment: Sorry just Tom. Which country is INDIA in?